# clion has more problems indicators than vscode when writing code

Tags: c

I was making a project and one of my friends told me to try clion.
I didn't really like it but the only difference that made me stay in clion is when I am writing code, Clion gives more alerts like: this code is unreachable or this function always returns 0.
these are the things that made me stay but I wondered, why does is it different from vscode and can I get it in vscode ?

Comment: In your VS code enable more warnings :) an you will have the same

Comment: In general, JetBrains IDEs have many more features than VSCode. So why is this surprising?